# Angular2 : HTTP Observables flow is not clear

Tags: angular

In my component i am calling Rest service and want to save the data, The Rest call is not successful(**expected behaviour**) so i was expecting this code to be executed:

> err => console.log(err) && this.accessLevel==AccessLevel.DISBLED

```
export class CustomerComponent extends SuperChildComponent{
  public static url:string='/orderViewCustomer/';
  public id;
  public allowed: boolean = false;
  public  accessLevel:AccessLevel =null;
  public componentname:string;
  public customerData:Customer=null;

  constructor(private rest:REST,private authenticationService : AuthorizationService) {
    super();
    this.componentname=this.constructor.name;
     this.accessLevel=this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()?this.authenticationService.componentAccessLevel(this.constructor.name):null;
     console.log(this.constructor.name +' has '+this.accessLevel);
     if(this.accessLevel==AccessLevel.ENABLED){
       this.getData();
     }
  }

  private getData():any{
    this.rest.get(CustomerComponent.url,this.id).subscribe(data=> this.storeData(data.json()), err => console.log(err) && this.accessLevel==AccessLevel.DISBLED);
  }



private storeData(res:Object):any{
            //TODO
      //this.customerData =<Customer>res;
   this.customerData=<Customer>this.dummy;
}
```

This is the get method from my rest service:

```
get(resource: string, id: number, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()) {
    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;
    headers.set("Authorization", this.authdata);
    return this
        .http
        .get(this.getUrl(resource) + '/' + id, params);
    // .map((r: Response) => r.json());
}
```

**but error block is never executed and so does the storeData(dat.json()) function.**

Does subscriber blocks get executed only when call is successful ?

Is there anything i am missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please define 'not successful'? Does it return an error code or is the connection not at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribe(...)` supports 3 callbacks

```
someObservable.subscribe(
  data => this.onSuccessDoSomething(data),
  err => this.onErrorDoSomethingElse(err),
  () => this.afterObservableCompleted() // after the last onSuccess...
)
```

Comment: It is important to notice that 'onCompleted' is not being called in the error case, but only in the 'onNext' case.

Comment: Are you implying that the code doesn't work because he is missing a parameter? If so then I then I think JavaScript will pass null for the 3rd argument and the call should still work.

Comment: Just tried to answer the question "Does subscriber blocks get executed only when call is successful ?"